# Display file uploaded to Aws S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/<Bucket_name>?region=us-east-2&prefix=media/<filename>
```

is the url I want to save to my custom Abstractuser from file upload. How would you upload a file to override the user avatar field from the views.py?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserProfileForm

def index(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

The retrieving part works.

```
<img class="profile-pic" src="{{user.avatar.url}}" >
<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Will currently display the avatar associated with the user.

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/<Bucket_name>?region=us-east-2&prefix=media/default.png
```

model.py

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='', null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

from pages.models import Profile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            #validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 100
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Please use an image that is '
                     '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

            #validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                    'GIF or PNG image.')

            #validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar
```

Settings.py

```
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION )
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'portfolio.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```